# Rendering errors in proper format inside under on Mojolicious::Lite

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I have an `under` statement that may generate and error (for instance, authentication error). I use content negotiation all over, and I'd like to return the error inside the `under` in a proper format. An example code:

```
under sub {
  my $self = shift;

  # Authenticated
  my $token = $self->param('token') || '';
  return 1 if $token eq '123456';

  # Not authenticated
  $self->respond_to(
    json => {
      json => { error => 'Invalid authentication token.' },
      status => 401
    },
    text => {
      text => 'Unauthorized.',
      status => 401
    }
  );
  return undef;
}
```

I can use `render` inside `under`, but `respond_to` won't work. Probably `under` work for that. But in that case, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Galileo](https://github.com/jberger/Galileo/blob/master/lib/Galileo.pm#L96) I have an `auth_fail` helper which does something like this. While I work out an example, see that code (and the `if_author` and `if_admin` `under`s).

Ok here is an example, the trick turned out to be (at least for this mechanism) before you can redirect to your failure handler, you need to `flash` the format, which make it available to the next handler.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

any '/fail' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->respond_to(
    json => {
      json => { error => 'Invalid authentication token.' },
      status => 401
    },
    text => {
      text => 'Unauthorized.',
      status => 401
    }
  );
};

under sub {
  my $self = shift;

  # Authenticated
  my $token = $self->param('token') || '';
  return 1 if $token eq '123456';

  # Not authenticated
  $self->flash( format => $self->param('format') );
  $self->redirect_to('fail');
  return undef;
};

any '/private' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->respond_to(
    json => {
      json => { launch_codes => '9999999' },
    },
    text => {
      text => 'Launch Code: 9999999',
    }
  ); 
};

app->start;
```